# Get a known folder in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin.android, directory

I'm developing an Android application for my thesis with Xamarin. I need to export a file in a folder I can access via my PC, doesn't matter what (Documents, Pictures, Music).

I'm using this code to get the folders' path:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

In the manifest, I've included these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Substituting MyDocuments with the others enum, I get these paths:

```
Folder MyDocuments: /data/data/MagMapTimeDroid.MagMapTimeDroid/files
Folder MyMusic: /data/data/MagMapTimeDroid.MagMapTimeDroid/files/Music
Folder MyPictures: /data/data/MagMapTimeDroid.MagMapTimeDroid/files/Pictures
Folder CommonDocuments: /* EMPTY STRING */
Folder CommonPictures:  /* EMPTY STRING */
Folder ApplicationData: /data/data/MagMapTimeDroid.MagMapTimeDroid/files/.config
Folder Desktop: /data/data/MagMapTimeDroid.MagMapTimeDroid/files/Desktop
```

No one of these paths is accessible via pc. I'm using a Galaxy Tab 2 (7") with CyanogenMod and Android 5.1.1.

So, the question is: how can I access a public folder in order to write the file and get it from pc?

Thank you,

Luca

Answer (score 0):

> So, the question is: how can I access a public folder in order to write the file and get it from pc?

You can use the DDMS tool to get the file from your android device and then pull the file from the android device to your PC, after you complete to write this file from PC, you can then push this file again to the device.

To use DDMS tool with VS2015, you can open your android project with VS2015 and click the icon to Open **Android Device Monitor(DDMS)**:

[image]

Then if your android device is already connected to PC, you can find it in the **Devices** List on the left side of DDMS, select this device, then on the right side, go to the table **File Explorer**, and find your app which should be installed in this android device:

[image]

In the files folder, you should be able to find your file.

To pull and push the files, you can click the buttons here:

[image]

Comment: The app folders are in a particular folder?

Comment: @lukemols, directly open file explorer of DDMS, you can find folders for each app which is installed in this device.

Comment: I can't find any app folder here. There are only the system app folders under "System/App" and "System/priv-app".

Comment: @lukemols, connect your device to your pc, open ddms, then debug your app on your device, then you can in the file explorer find the `data folder`, then `app folder` then your app's folder, have you found that?

Answer (score 0):

To get one of the known or 'public' folders you have to use the external storage directory environment strings.

The example below saves to the public "My Documents" folder of a samsung s6.

```
    public void Save(string filename, string data)
    {
        var docPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        docPath = Path.Combine(docPath, "My Documents");
        var filepath = Path.Combine(docPath, filename);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, data);
    }
```

When you look at the string returned by the `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath` it may look funny but it is actually getting the root public folder of the device, I then add the my documents folder to it and then append the filename to the end.

Let me know if this does not work for you.